# What does canvas' size depend on?

Tags: android, size, screen, android-canvas, screen-size

I would like to understand what affects the `Canvas` size.

I have tried my app with two different devices, which are two variants of Samsung Galaxy S III: **SGH-T999** and **GT-I9300**.

Both of them have screen resolution of **720*1280**, but their `Canvas` sizes are different:
While on the **GT-I9300**, the `Canvas` uses the whole screen (Its size is also 720*1280), on the  **SGH-T999** it uses only 656*1070.

Why does this happen? What changes the `Canvas` size?

Answer (score 0):

The system bar (software buttons) needs some space, and affects the actual Canvas size.

Comment: There are no software buttons on Galaxy S III.